# Fetch Data from Dynamic array field in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I want to fetch data from a dynamic array field. My sample doc is

```
Document1:[
“Docid” : 11111,
"store": {
      “100”: {
        "istock": false,
        "price": 0
      },
      "289": {
        "inStock": false,
        "price": 0
      },
      "1561": {
        "inStock": false,
        "price": 0
      }, 
   }]
```

please do help. any suggestions appreciated. NOTE: no Index created in the store field currently.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the value

```
SELECT d.store.`100`.price, d.store.`100`.inStock
FROM default AS d
WHERE ....;
```

If you want to index and search based on sub fields

CREATE INDEX ix1 ON default( DISTINCT ARRAY v.price FOR v IN OBJECT_VALUES(store) END);

```
SELECT d.*
FROM default AS d
WHERE ANY v IN OBJECT_VALUES(d.store) SATISFIES v.inStock = true END;
```

Checkout OBJECT_PAIRS(), OBJECT_NAMES(), OBJECT_VALUES()